# Add custom recognizer delay

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, delay

I've disabled `delaysContentTouches` in my tableview subclass using:

```
delaysContentTouches = false
subviews.forEach { ($0 as? UIScrollView)?.delaysContentTouches = false }
```

But in one of my sections, I still want to keep the delay. Is there a way to cancel the delay for certain sections or perhaps I can add a custom recognizer delay to a section?

Answer (score 0):

Sections are not actual objects within a tableView, so my answer to your first question is no. The `.delaysContentTouches` applies to the entire tableView.

For your second inquiry, I believe that one way it could be possible is through setting a delay for desired cells' scrollView subview. In your tableView(cellForRowAt: indexPath) func, you could have something like this:

```
if indexPath.section == 3 { //or whatever your desired section is
    for view in cell.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            let currentView = view as! UIScrollView
            currentView.delaysContentTouches = true
        }
    }
}
```

This will find the UIScrollView in your cell's subviews in your desired section. It will then set the `.delaysContentTouches` property accordingly.

I have not personally executed this code, just researched it, so let me know if it works.

**Edit**

Apparently the UIScrollView in UITableViewCell has been deprecated, so the above method will not work anymore.

My next best suggestion to you is to use a UILongPressGuestureRecognizer. This will not be quite the same thing as delaying the touch, but could have a similar effect in real execution.

You could use it in the same tableView(cellForRowAt: indexPath) func as so:

```
let press = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePress))
press.minimumPressDuration = 2.0 //however long you want
cell.addGestureRecognizer(press)
```

Whatever you are trying to achieve by selecting certain rows of your tableView could be placed in the `handlePress` func above which would be trigged upon the long press.

Comment: I've also found similar answers like the one you've posted. Unfortunately it doesn't work (anymore). The cell also doesn't seem to have any `UIScrollView` in the subviews either.

Comment: @HennyLee Yeah I wasn't sure if it was still in use or not. Check my updated post for another suggestion.